# How to change the icon of html files?

Tags: windows, icons, gui, file-types, windows-shell

Windows (at least XP and Vista, I haven't tried 7) refuses to honor my setting of the icon to show for html files. It insist in showing the paper sheet with the IE logo on it.

On XP I changed the icon through `Folder options > File Types` and for Vista I used [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html). But it does not work at all.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application could have installed an *Icon Handler* to provide a custom icon depending on file contents. For example, Microsoft Office installs icon handler to display custom icons for HTML files created in Word or Excel.

If there's an *Icon Handler*, Windows wouldn't use icon from `DefaultIcon`.

So try to remove the key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shellex\IconHandler
```

Then Explorer will use icon specified in `DefaultIcon`:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\DefaultIcon
```

There's no need to restart Explorer. If the icon does not change immediately, then restart Explorer.

---

Otherwise grvanchal [provided steps](https://superuser.com/a/561908/80304) to change the icon.

Comment: This works, but it breaks existing functionality, i.e. those files meant to show a custom icon will show the default instead. The `Icon handler` has its own default icon (which is different from the Windows' default), is it possible to set somewhere else the `Icon Handler`'s default?

Comment: @GetFree I guess there's no easy way around it: you either have the Icon Handler or not. If there's an icon handler, it has the full control over the displayed icon. The handler DLL from MS Office 2007 has no icons in it. I'm pretty sure, there are no icons in the handler DLL in subsequent Office versions so it extracts the icons from other files. One can think it should use the `DefaultIcon` setting where customized icons are not applicable. And I agree. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @GetFree I don't know from where Office extracts the icons. If you find that DLL or EXE, you can modify the default icon to something else. You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see which files the Icon Handler opens. However it wouldn't be an easy task since Explorer uses many shell extensions.

Answer (score 2):

The values for icons are located in registry.

Go to RUN and type regedit

```
Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html
```

Then check the default. For example I have chromium browser So my default key is ChromiumHTM.

Go to the name of key in default:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\{YOUR DEFAULT BROWSER KEY}\DefaultIcon
```

Example:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromiumHTM\DefaultIcon
```

Change the default value for that key to desired icon. Restart explorer.exe and your icon is changed.

Comment: The default type says `htmlfile`. I went to that key, and under `DefaultIcon` is the exact path I set myself with FileTypesMan.

Comment: Did you kill the process and start the explorer.exe or restart?

Comment: Yes, I restarted, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you Other way for using Different Icon for your HTML file. Its totally different way but It could give you the Result you want....

Right click on Desktop >> New >> Shortcut
And Choose your File.
Then You can Change Icon of that Shortcut by
Right click on it >> Properties >> Change Icon.
Then you can Move That Shortcut file anywhere you want to

Comment: Yes, but  search the same question on Internet and  came on this Page. I read those Answer I was also thinking like This might Help someone other who is having same question. and If he want the result as me.. :)

Answer (score -1):

A solution from [link](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/34226-35-icon-change-take)

Right click Desktop, go to Properties>Appearance
Click "Advanced", choose "Icon" and change size to something other than it's current size.
Press "OK" to confirm changes in all relevant dialogue windows.
When the icons have changed, restore the size to its original value.

This should force a redraw of all icons, clearing the old images.

Comment: The problem is not the icon cache. I used TweakUI to rebuld the icons, but they stay the same.